# ARIMA - Identifying an outlier in residuals

Tags: time-series, arima, outliers, diagnostic, acf-pacf

I am trying to perform an ARIMA (SARIMAX in fact) and when looking at the residuals I see a large outlier. I am using python `statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax`.

[image]

I have two data series of equal length. There is no voluminous increase in either data series at the start.

Sample:

endog = [-3.6055070639, -3.5962072768, -3.9217236984 ... ]

exog = [ -313.6481703357, -296.7099369162, -279.7743483934 ... ]

residuals = [1281.410360, -0.563979, -4.569989]

I cannot work out where this outlier comes from, and I do not know where to start looking.

- I have tried setting differencing to 0 in case it was an issue with differencing at the first or last value.
- I have tried contracting my data frame as to be certain it's not the data.
- have tried changing p and q just in case.

p and q are set to 1, seasonal values set to 0.

I don't think this can be directly solved via a forum but I would like to know where to start looking for an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plot does not show residuals. It shows the autocorrelation function (ACF) of the residuals, i.e. the values of autocorrelation $\text{Corr}(u_t,u_{t-h})=1$ for a numer of different lags $h$. Naturally, at lag zero the autocorrelation equals one: $\text{Corr}(u_t,u_{t-0})=\text{Corr}(u_t,u_{t})=1$. This is nothing to worry about.

There are some other lags ($h=7,8,9$ and some more distant ones) with statistically significant autocorrelations. They indicate the model is not entirely adequate. But these values are quite small, so they might not be economically significant, and the model may be "good enough".